# Erro 404 Servlet

Tags: java, servlet

Estou com um erro que é o seguinte sempre que eu acesso a URL que meu servlet tinha que responder ele me apresenta erro 404, eu estou tentando acessar a servlet por essa url: localhost:8080/projeto/oa

Aqui esta o código fonte da servlet: http://pastebin.com/qhPu2L7V

Aqui esta o código fonte do web.xml: http://pastebin.com/Pm0PmHsX

Esse é o contexto do projeto.

[image: Esse é o contexto do projeto.]

Comment: Qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Porque não funciona.

Comment: Fornecer códigos é sempre melhor que imagens, a não ser quando estamos falado de renderização gráfica, aonde é preferivel enviar imagem e código (se houver). Mas o caso não é grafico, portanto se puder fornecer o código e detalhes de como configurou você irá ajudar os outros a te ajudarem. Leia para entender como funciona a comunidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Você está iniciando o servidor web pelo eclipse?

Comment: Sim estou inciando o server pelo eclipse.

Comment: Galera já postei o código fonte pelo pastebin.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Erro 404 com Servlet Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51177/erro-404-com-servlet-java)

Comment: Se possível, coloque o `log` de deploy do servidor que você está usando. Pode ser que o deploy não esteja funcionando corretamente.